# Wildfly Failed to create netty connection

Tags: java, jboss, netty, wildfly

I'm have Wildfly AS setup on my raspberry pi 2, I added a HornetQ using this cmd:

```
jms-queue add --queue-address=demoQueue --entries=java:/jms/queue/demoQueue,java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/demoQueue
```

I'm debugging a sender app on a different machine in IntelliJ.

I'm using the standalone-full.xml config and have edited it following [this](http://bgasparotto.com/enable-wildfly-remote-access/) guide to enable remote connection

My application fails when it reaches :
`connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME), System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD));`

The output I get is:

```
    INFO: JBoss Remoting version 4.0.9.Final
    Nov 21, 2015 8:33:43 PM Sender main
    INFO: Attempting to acquire connection factory "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"
    Nov 21, 2015 8:33:45 PM Sender main
    INFO: Found connection factory "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" in JNDI
    Nov 21, 2015 8:33:45 PM Sender main
    INFO: Attempting to acquire destination "java:/jms/queue/demoQueue"
    Nov 21, 2015 8:33:45 PM Sender main
    INFO: Found destination "java:/jms/queue/demoQueue" in JNDI
    Nov 21, 2015 8:33:48 PM org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector createConnection
    ERROR: HQ214016: Failed to create netty connection
    java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.checkAddress(Net.java:101)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:622)
```

After reading a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28913520/required-ports-for-jms-using-hornetq-jboss-to-expose-on-docker-container)

I think my problem might be the same, I tried to add  a new outbound socket-binding entry but Wildfly crashed when I rebooted it so I removed the settings I'd added.

Is my problem caused by setting up remote and can it be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this buy setting:

```
<interface name="public">
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
```

To:

```
<interface name="public">
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:My-Host-Address}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you.  It wouldn't work for me w/ the jboss.bind.address included but using the ip-address of the machine worked fine.