# Wildfly AS bind to domain for remote connections

Tags: java, jboss, jms, wildfly

I have a `Wildfly AS` setup with a `HorentQ` deployed on it for `JMS` between two standalone applications.

The `AS` is running on my raspberry pi 2, I have the IP address of the pi set up in my `standalone-full.xml`

```
 <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.1.6}"/>
    </interface>
```

This allows me to access the Wildfly AS From any other machines within my network using `String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://192.168.1.6:8080";`.

Currently I'm trying to access the AS from outside my network using a personal domain `myurl.com` that comes in on port: 80 and points to the port I have Wildfly setup on: 8080.

I have no problem accessing the management interface from a browser because I have the management binding setup as: `bind.address.managment :0.0.0.0`

But if I try to use `myurl.com` in my applications

`String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://myurl.com";` it fails:

> SEVERE: Failed to connect to any server. Servers tried: [http-remoting://myurl.com (java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: connect)]

I can't change: `<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.1.6}"/>`

to: `<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>`

Because then the netty connection will try to bind to that address and fail,
as discussed in an earlier  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33848395/wildfly-failed-to-create-netty-connection)

I also cant set the binding like this:

`<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:http://myurl.com/}"/>`

So how do I allow remote connections to my `Wildfly AS` using: `myurl.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have stuck with this a little longer before asking this question, I wont take it down though as it might help others.

The solution was quite simple, I left all my configuration as was and simply appended `:80` to the end of the `String`

```
String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://myurl.com:80";
```

Connected straight away.